# Tweak smooth scrolling code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn jQuery and I'm having a mental blank at the moment. The following code scrolls my page to the top with a smooth transition, but I would like this smooth transition to work for all anchor/ID links on my site (it's only a one pager).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a[href="#the-top"]').click(function (e) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#the-top').offset().top }, 1000);
        return false;
    });

});
```

How can I change my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a[href^=#]').bind('click', function (evt) {
        var $what = $('#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1]);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $what.offset().top }, 1000);
        evt.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Changes suggested in this code:

- Change global `$` object to `jQuery`
- Just `jQuery(fn)` as `document.ready(fn)`
- Closure: use `jQuery` as `$` inside that function
- Prevent default event from anchor instead of `return false` (source: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)
- Use of `$what` asking for the `#something` part of anchor href, in order to prevent misbehaviors in IE (because if you have `href="#some"` sometimes it become `href="http://yoursite.com/yourcurrentpage/#some` instead)

All of these are kind of optional. You get the idea. Feel free to change.

DEMO AT: http://jsfiddle.net/Nm3cT/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Chris Coyier's smooth Scrolling script](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/). It does exactly that and needs no further configuration. Plus, it updates the address on the browser.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use Chris' script but it conflicts with some pre-existing jQuery on my site unfortunately!

Comment: How does it conflict? You might try using jQuery.noConflict() or isolating Chris' script. Like so:

(function($){
// insert Chris' script here.
})(jQuery);